# How to create a static mutable hashmap?

Tags: rust

How do I create a static mutable hashmap?  I am ok with unsafe code.

The normal static does not allow globals with constructors.

As an example, I want what is at https://gist.github.com/Kimundi/8782487 but HASHMAP to be mutable.

I understand that global shared mutable state is not what very rust-ish but I just want to know if such a thing is possible.

Comment: As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You may also want to add some background to your question. It really sounds like you are asking how to have global mutable shared data, which is pretty against-the-grain for Rust.

Comment: You might be able to adapt Kimundi's gist be having it implement DerefMut instead of Deref.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For maintained answers, see [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/155423), as this question should have been marked as a duplicate.

---

Seeing as how you already have a solution for a global object that is non-mutable, perhaps you can use one of the [`cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html) containers to add interior mutability?

Realistically, this sounds like a a *bad idea*. Global mutable state is problematic. Why can't you pass in a mutable hashmap to the methods / objects that need it?

You may also what to check out [the implementation of `stdin`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4b40bc85cbc1d072179c92ce01655db0272aa598/src/libstd/io/stdio.rs#L215-L245), which provides safe access to a true global singleton.

Comment: Thank you.  Your link to stdin is exactly what I'm looking for and also a great example of when this is appropriate.