# Update / re-initialize a var defined in lazy_static

Tags: rust

I have a config that I want initialized on startup, but not have to re-read the file every time. To do this, I'm using lazy_static:

```rust
lazy_static! {
  static ref SETTINGS: Settings = {
    match Settings::init() {
      Ok(c) => c,
      Err(e) => panic!("{}", e),
    }
  };
}
```

But now I have a method that updates that config file, and I want to "re-initialize" / update it, without having to re-start the program.

```rust
  pub fn save_config_file(data: &str) -> Result<String, Error> {
    fs::write(CONFIG_FILE, data)?;
    SETTINGS = {
      match Settings::init() {
        Ok(c) => c, // The line with the error
        Err(e) => panic!("{}", e),
      }
    };

    Self::read_config_file()
  }
```

Which gives me the error: `[rustc E0308] [E] mismatched types expected struct settings::SETTINGS, found struct settings::Settings`

Is there any way to re-initialize a lazy_static? Or do I have to restart the program?

Comment: You can use a RefCell to change the contents of a lazy static.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere, how RefCell works with lazy_static?

Comment: RefCell works the same anywhere. It allows you to mutate its contents, even if you only have a immutable reference to the RefCell.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you probably shouldn't be using lazy satic to hold settings, and should instead initialize the settings in your main function/early function, and then pass references around,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton)

Comment: (@PiRocks Note that because statics must be thread safe, you need to use `Mutex`, `RwLock` or atomics -- `RefCell` would work with a `thread_local` though.)

Answer (score 4):

Okay, figured this one out. Mainly from here: [How do I assign a String to a mutable static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654927/how-do-i-assign-a-string-to-a-mutable-static-variable/47181804#47181804)

Add derive Clone to your struct:

`#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Clone)]`

Wrap your lazy_static in an `RwLock`, initialize it normally.

```rust
use std::sync::RwLock;

lazy_static! {
  static ref SETTINGS: RwLock<Settings> = RwLock::new(
    match Settings::init() {
      Ok(c) => c,
      Err(e) => panic!("{}", e),
    }
  );
}
```

To read, you can do this:

```rust
  pub fn get() -> Self {
    SETTINGS.read().unwrap().to_owned()
  }
```

To write:

```rust
    let mut new_settings = SETTINGS.write().unwrap();
    *new_settings = match Settings::init() {
      Ok(c) => c,
      Err(e) => panic!("{}", e),
    };
```