# file-scope mutable static HashSet/Vec/etc

Tags: rust, ld-preload

I'd like to create C-linkage functions to intercept my program's calls via `LD_PRELOAD` but I'm implementing the interception functions in Rust.

I have no problem creating the `pub extern fn` to intercept the calls but I'd like to read/write from the program's global state somewhere since I can't alter the signature of the functions I'm intercepting to accept the metadata.  I don't need heap allocation necessarily, I could live with some large statically initialized pool of `HashSet` or `Vec` entries.  But I do need to be able to add and remove elements of the collection during the program's run.

I recognize that this pattern is contrary to many Rust design goals and yet it seems like a legitimate use case to me.

I'm brand new to Rust, so I'm hoping that there's an `unsafe` option out there to do this.

If it's useful to see code examples:

```
static mut foo Vec<c_int> = Vec::new();
```

...fails because you can't have `static` storage that requires a destructor, or does heap allocations.  And `lazy_static!` doesn't allow for `mut`able structures.

Ideally I'd prefer a `HashSet<c_int>`.  If I can't get that to work, I suppose I could try a `Vec::from_elem(100, 0)`.  That's not ideal since I'll need to nominate some kind of sentry value, but if it works I think I'd be satisfied.

Comment: I suspect [this and similar answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27826181/489590) will be satisfactory.

Comment: *lazy_static! doesn't allow for mutable structures* — just put a `Mutex` or equivalent in there. I updated the linked question with an example; you can mark this question as a duplicate of that one if it's good enough for you.