# Global mutable HashMap in a library

Tags: hashmap, rust, libraries

I want to have an extendable dictionary linking together `Object` with a `&'static str` inside my library. `HashMap` seems like the right data structure for this, but how do I make it global, initialised on declaration and mutable?

So something like this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

enum Object { A, B, C }

const OBJECT_STR: &'static [&'static str] = &[ "a", "b", "c" ];

static mut word_map: HashMap<&'static str, Object> = {
    let mut m = HashMap::new();
    m.insert(OBJECT_STR[0], Object::A);
    m.insert(OBJECT_STR[1], Object::B);
    m.insert(OBJECT_STR[2], Object::C);
    m
};

impl Object {
...
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This would be possible with the [`lazy_static`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lazy-static.rs) crate. As seen in their example. Since mutablity accessing a static variable is unsafe, it would need to wrapped into a [`Mutex`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html). I would recommend not making the `HashMap` public, but instead provide a set of methods that lock, and provide access to the `HashMap`. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton) on making a globally mutable singleton.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Mutex;

lazy_static! {
    static ref HASHMAP: Mutex<HashMap<u32, &'static str>> = {
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        m.insert(0, "foo");
        m.insert(1, "bar");
        m.insert(2, "baz");
        Mutex::new(m)
    };    
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = HASHMAP.lock().unwrap();
    map.insert(3, "sample");
}
```