# What is the idiomatic way to implement caching on a function that is not a struct method?

Tags: caching, rust, static-members

I have an expensive function like this:

```
pub fn get_expensive_value(n: u64): u64 {
   let ret = 0;
   for 0 .. n {
       // expensive stuff
   }
   ret
}
```

And it gets called very frequently with the same argument. It's pure, so that means it will return the same result and can make use of a cache.

If this was a struct method, I would add a member to the struct that acts as a cache, but it isn't. So my option seems to be to use a static:

```
static mut LAST_VAL: Option<(u64, u64)> = None;

pub fn cached_expensive(n: u64) -> u64 {
   unsafe {
       LAST_VAL = LAST_VAL.and_then(|(k, v)| {
           if k == n {
              Some((n,v))
           } else {
              None
           }
       }).or_else(|| {
           Some((n, get_expensive_value(n)))
       });
       let (_, v) = LAST_VAL.unwrap();
       v
   }
}
```

Now, I've had to use `unsafe`. Instead of the `static mut`, I could use a `RefCell` but I'm not convinced that is any safer - it just avoids having to use the `unsafe` block. I thought about a `Mutex`, but I don't think that will get me thread safety either.

Redesigning the code to use a struct for storage is not really an option.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton).

Comment: Or you can alter the signature of `cached_expensive` to accept the cache as another parameter.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. My question is specifically about caching and, while my starting point is a global, mutable singleton, that is incidental and a good solution might explain how (for example) a `RefCell` or `Mutex` could make this better, or offer a completely different alternative structurally.

Comment: I disagree, but I won't use the magic dupehammer until others agree with me. In short, there's *nowhere* else to store data. Either you pass in a place to store it (via an explicit argument or implicitly via `self`) or it has to be stored in global storage. The latter has the restriction that you are required to handle concurrent access to the cache.

Comment: While I'm not quite able to reason it out right now, I have a feeling that the proposed `unsafe` block in the question doesn't uphold the safety guarantees that it is required to. For example, I'm pretty sure that concurrent calls to the function can have partial reads/writes to the storage (as there's no mutual exclusion), causing strange behavior in arbitrary circumstances.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, this was my concern, which led me to post the question. I have read the question that you linked to as a dupe, and it's actually very helpful. The `Arc<Mutex<..>>` construction looks like what I need. But I am going to rethink if I can't just do this differently. I'm coming into an existing codebase, so it's not so straightforward..

Comment: @Shepmaster is right. Your code as written will permit unsynchronized reads/writes to the same location in memory. The `lazy_static` approach in the question linked is probably what you want. (To a first approximation. There may be faster approaches...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the best alternative is to use a global variable with a mutex. Using lazy_static makes it easy and allows the "global" declaration inside the function

```
pub fn cached_expensive(n: u64) -> u64 {
    use std::sync::Mutex;
    lazy_static! {
        static ref LAST_VAL: Mutex<Option<(u64, u64)>> = Mutex::new(None);
    }
    let mut last = LAST_VAL.lock().unwrap();
    let r = last.and_then(|(k, v)| {
        if k == n {
            Some((n, v))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }).or_else(|| Some((n, get_expensive_value(n))));
    let (_, v) = r.unwrap();
    *last = r;
    v
}
```

Comment: So you agree this is a duplicate of [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton) as suggested in the comments?

Comment: Yes. But I decide to write the answer to show that the global variable can be declared inside the function, so the scope is local.

Answer (score 8):

You can also check out the [cached](https://github.com/jaemk/cached) project / crate. It memoizes the function with a simple macro.