# How can I implement a fetch-cached-or-load operation in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I’m trying to create a simple cache that has one operation: “get from
cache, loading if necessary”. Here’s a [working example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5ac3dc50c17f3ea7763051f9a12df55c) (just
using file loading for simplicity):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct FileCache {
    /// Map storing contents of loaded files.
    files: HashMap<PathBuf, Vec<u8>>,
}

impl FileCache {
    /// Get a file's contents, loading it if it hasn't yet been loaded.
    pub fn get(&mut self, path: &Path) -> io::Result<&[u8]> {
        if let Some(_) = self.files.get(path) {
            println!("Cached");
            return Ok(self.files.get(path).expect("just checked"));
        }
        let buf = self.load(path)?;
        Ok(self.files.entry(path.to_owned()).or_insert(buf))
    }
    /// Load a file, returning its contents.
    fn load(&self, path: &Path) -> io::Result<Vec<u8>> {
        println!("Loading");
        let mut buf = Vec::new();
        use std::io::Read;
        File::open(path)?.read_to_end(&mut buf)?;
        Ok(buf)
    }
}

pub fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut store = FileCache::default();
    let path = Path::new("src/main.rs");
    println!("Length: {}", store.get(path)?.len());
    println!("Length: {}", store.get(path)?.len());
    Ok(())
}
```

The success branch of the `if let` has an extra call to `self.files.get`
and an extra `expect`. We just called that and pattern-matched on its
result, so we should like to just return the match:

```rust
    pub fn get(&mut self, path: &Path) -> io::Result<&[u8]> {
        if let Some(x) = self.files.get(path) {
            println!("Cached");
            return Ok(x);
        }
        let buf = self.load(path)?;
        Ok(self.files.entry(path.to_owned()).or_insert(buf))
    }
```

But this [fails the borrow checker](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0eedc8bb5241900902567f861773cd04):

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.files` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:20:12
   |
14 |     pub fn get(&mut self, path: &Path) -> io::Result<&[u8]> {
   |                - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
15 |         if let Some(x) = self.files.get(path) {
   |                          ---------- immutable borrow occurs here
16 |             println!("Cached");
17 |             return Ok(x);
   |                    ----- returning this value requires that `self.files` is borrowed for `'1`
...
20 |         Ok(self.files.entry(path.to_owned()).or_insert(buf))
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

I don’t understand why these two versions behave differently. Isn’t
`self.files` borrowed for `&self` lifetime in both cases? In the first
form, we drop the borrow and obtain a new one, but I don’t see why that
should make a difference. How does the second form enable me to violate
memory safety, and how can I write this code without the extra lookup
and `expect` check?

I’ve read [How do I write a rust function that can both read and write to a cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55859983), which is related, but
the answers there either duplicate the lookup (as in my working example)
or clone the value (prohibitively expensive), so aren’t sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both implementations should be legal Rust code. The fact that `rustc` rejected the second one is actually a bug as tracked by [issue 58910](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/58910).

Let's elaborate:

```rust
pub fn get(&mut self, path: &Path) -> io::Result<&[u8]> {
    if let Some(x) = self.files.get(path) { // ---+ x
        println!("Cached");                    // |
        return Ok(x);                          // |
    }                                          // |
    let buf = self.load(path)?;                // |
    Ok(self.files.entry(path.to_owned())       // |
        .or_insert(buf))                       // |
}                                              // v
```

By binding to variable `x` in let some expression, `self.files` is borrowed as immutable. The same `x` is later returned out to the caller, which implies `self.files` remains borrowed until some point in the caller. So in current Rust borrow checker implementation, `self.files` is **unnecessarily** kept being borrowed the whole `get` function. It can't be borrowed again later on as mutable. The fact that `x` is never used after the early return is not taken into consideration.

Your first implementation works as a workaround to this. Since `let some(_) = ...` doesn't create any binding, it doesn't have the same problem. It does incur additional runtime cost though due to multiple lookups.

This is the [problem case #3](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2094-nll.md#problem-case-3-conditional-control-flow-across-functions) described in Niko's NLL RFC. Good news is:

> TL;DR: Polonius is supposed to fix this.

([Polonius](https://github.com/rust-lang/polonius) is the more sophisticated 3rd incarnation of Rust borrow checker which is still in developement).

Comment: Fascinating. Thanks for the reference! I’ll keep around the extra runtime cost for now, then (my application isn’t concurrent, so it’s just runtime cost and not a correctness issue), and look into Polonius in more detail. Thank you!

Comment: @wchargin yeah, this is not a soundness issue. rustc rejects something it shouldn't have. A bit annoying, that's all.