# Globals of type Option<...> in Rust

Tags: rust, global

I can not get the following piece of code to work:

```
extern crate gtk

use gtk::prelude::*
use gtk::Window;
use gtk::WindowType;
// ...

static mut appWindow: Option<Window> = None;

fn main() {
    // ...
    appWindow = Some(Window::new(WindowType::Toplevel))
    // ...
}
```

The compiler produces the error:

```
error: mutable statics are not allowed to have destructors [E0397]
static mut appWindow: Option<Window> = None;
```

Surrounding everything with `unsafe { ... }` doesn't help.

Comment: `Optional` is not a type provided by the standard library. Where does it come from? Is it provided by the GTK crate? Please produce a [MCVE] when asking a question on Stack Overflow. You may also be interested in [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton). You should also note that Rust style is `snake_case`, not `camelCase` (should be `app_window`).

Comment: @Shepmaster It is from `std::option::Option`, as far as I am concerned. But it seems that I don't need to explicitly import it, for some reason. And explicitly importing it changes nothing.

Comment: See [this link](http://rustbyexample.com/std/option.html). This is where I got that `Optional<...>`-part from.

Comment: `Optional` is very different from `Option`. It's not extremely useful to ask for help on code that has invalid syntax, thus why a [MCVE] is highly recommended. For example, I'd bet that `Optional` [sic] is a red-herring here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's code that reproduces the same error that you've shown:

```
struct Foo;

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}

static mut f: Foo = Foo;

fn main() {}
```

Produces the errors:

```
error: mutable statics are not allowed to have destructors [E0397]
static mut f: Foo = Foo;
                    ^~~

error: statics are not allowed to have destructors [E0493]
static mut f: Foo = Foo;
                    ^~~
```

As the message says, Rust disallows having any kind of static item with destructors. A proposed [change to the language](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1111) discusses the origin of this:

> This was historically motivated by the question of when to run the
>   destructor:
>
> - There where worries about supporting life before/after main() for, eg, static variables due to them having historically caused trouble
>     in, eg, C++ code bases.
> - Leaking the destructor was also for the most time not known to be a feasible option due to leaking possibly being bad.

[RFC 1440](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1440-drop-types-in-const.md) has been accepted to allow these types. As of Rust 1.9, there is an unstable feature that allows them: `#![feature(drop_types_in_const)]`.

As the RFC says:

> Destructors do not run on static items (by design), so this can lead to unexpected behavior when a type's destructor has effects outside the program (e.g. a RAII temporary folder handle, which deletes the folder on drop). However, this can already happen using the lazy_static crate.

Which leads to an alternate solution before the feature is stabilized: you can create a non-mutable static variable with lazy_static, which can then be wrapped in a thread-safe mutability wrapper. The type may contain a destructor:

[How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it is actually pretty interesting. But: Is there a way to use `Optional` or something different too have the possibility to use a `None`-like value? Or do I need to trick around with a `struct` that contains the `Optional`? (Without using unstable features)

Comment: @CodingLambdas there *still* isn't an `Optional` type. When placed in an `Option`, `Option` then has has a destructor that might need to be called, which isn't allowed in stable Rust as of 1.9.

Comment: Ok, I created a struct that contains the window. It still doesn't work (same error). And I didn't implement `Drop`.

Comment: Sry, I am used to writing `Optional`. As I already stated, I am new to Rust, coming from Python, and the snippet in the question was wrong because I didn't copy it. (Although I think I will never leave python... But it isn't compilable.)

Comment: @CodingLambdas *And I didn't implement `Drop`* — if your type contains a type that implements `Drop`, you can't "trick" the compiler into not calling it. `Drop` will be called unless you specifically go out of your way to forget the value (which wouldn't help for statics anyway).

Comment: Ok... So the conclusion is: I cannot use global variables for that without using unstable features.
Thanks!

Comment: @CodingLambdas did you read the link that has been posted twice that describes how to create global variables in stable Rust? Not that global variables are a *good* thing and I can **almost guarantee** you don't need it, but it's factually incorrect to say *I cannot use global variables for that without using unstable features*