# How do I share a HashMap between Hyper handlers?

Tags: rust, hyper

I'm attempting to learn Rust by implementing a simple in-memory URL shortener with Hyper 0.10. I'm running into an issue that I think is caused by trying to close over a mutable `HashMap` in my handler:

```
fn post(mut req: Request, mut res: Response, short_uris: &mut HashMap<&str, &str>) {
    let mut body = String::new();
    match req.read_to_string(&mut body) {
        Ok(_) => {
            let key = short_uris.len();
            short_uris.insert(&key.to_string(), &body.to_string());
            *res.status_mut() = StatusCode::Created;
            res.start().unwrap().write(&key.to_string().into_bytes());
        },
        Err(_) => *res.status_mut() = StatusCode::BadRequest
    }
}

fn get(req: Request, mut res: Response, short_uris: &HashMap<&str, &str>) {
    match req.uri.clone() {
        AbsolutePath(path) => {
            match short_uris.get::<str>(&path) {
                Some(short_uri) => {
                    *res.status_mut() = StatusCode::MovedPermanently;
                    res.headers_mut().set(Location(short_uri.to_string()));
                },
                None => *res.status_mut() = StatusCode::NotFound
            }
        },
        _ => *res.status_mut() = StatusCode::BadRequest
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut short_uris: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
    short_uris.insert("/example", "http://www.example.com");
    Server::http("0.0.0.0:3001").unwrap().handle(move |req: Request, mut res: Response| {
        match req.method {
            hyper::Post => post(req, res, &mut short_uris),
            hyper::Get => get(req, res, &short_uris),
            _ => *res.status_mut() = StatusCode::MethodNotAllowed
        }
    }).unwrap();
}
```

```
src/main.rs:42:40: 42:46 error: the trait bound `for<'r, 'r, 'r> [closure@src/main.rs:42:47: 48:3 short_uris:std::collections::HashMap<&str, &str>]: std::ops::Fn<(hyper::server::Request<'r, 'r>, hyper::server::Response<'r>)>` is not satisfied [E0277]
src/main.rs:42  Server::http("0.0.0.0:3001").unwrap().handle(move |req: Request, mut res: Response| {
```

Do I need to use an `Arc` to share the `HashMap` between threads? If so, what would that look like? Also, I could be totally wrong about the issue. The error message is very cryptic to me.

Comment: Why don't you declare the HashMap as global?

Comment: @Dr.Sahib I generally try to avoid global state. Also, I read the following SO post that recommended minimizing the use of global state: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton. So I was attempting to do it without global state.

Comment: Just noting that nightly Rust gives a lot better error message here: "expected a closure that implements the `Fn` trait, but this closure only implements `FnMut`"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please include all the necessary `use` declarations next time, thanks!

If you're using nightly Rust, the error message is a less cryptic:

> expected a closure that implements the `Fn`trait, but this closure only implements `FnMut`

That means that Hyper needs the closure to be shared between threads, so the closure needs to use its environment only via immutable or shared methods – so the usage of `&mut short_uris` is the offender here. To provide shared threadsafe mutability in Rust, you should use `Mutex` or `RwLock`.

Please note that you *don't* need `Arc` here – Hyper manages the ownership of the closure itself (probably by wrapping the closure in `Arc` under the hood, or using something like scoped-threads).

There's also second issue with your code – you use `HashMap<&str, &str>`. `&str` is a borrowed reference. Each time when you have something borrowed in Rust, you should ask yourself – from where? Here you try to borrow from really short-lived strings – `key.to_string()` and `body.to_string()`. It just can't work. Just make your hashmap fully owned – `HashMap<String, String>`. Here's the version of your code which compiles:

```
extern crate hyper;

use hyper::server::{Request, Response, Server};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use hyper::status::StatusCode;
use hyper::uri::RequestUri::AbsolutePath;
use hyper::header::Location;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn post(mut req: Request, mut res: Response, short_uris: &mut HashMap<String, String>) {
    let mut body = String::new();
    match req.read_to_string(&mut body) {
        Ok(_) => {
            let key = short_uris.len();
            short_uris.insert(key.to_string(), body);
            *res.status_mut() = StatusCode::Created;
            res.start()
                .unwrap()
                .write(&key.to_string().into_bytes())
                .unwrap();
        }
        Err(_) => *res.status_mut() = StatusCode::BadRequest,
    }
}

fn get(req: Request, mut res: Response, short_uris: &HashMap<String, String>) {
    match req.uri {
        AbsolutePath(ref path) => match short_uris.get(path) {
            Some(short_uri) => {
                *res.status_mut() = StatusCode::MovedPermanently;
                res.headers_mut().set(Location(short_uri.to_string()));
            }
            None => *res.status_mut() = StatusCode::NotFound,
        },
        _ => *res.status_mut() = StatusCode::BadRequest,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut short_uris: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
    short_uris.insert("/example".into(), "http://www.example.com".into());
    let short_uris = std::sync::RwLock::new(short_uris);
    Server::http("0.0.0.0:3001")
        .unwrap()
        .handle(move |req: Request, mut res: Response| match req.method {
            hyper::Post => post(req, res, &mut short_uris.write().unwrap()),
            hyper::Get => get(req, res, &short_uris.read().unwrap()),
            _ => *res.status_mut() = StatusCode::MethodNotAllowed,
        })
        .unwrap();
}
```

I've also got rid of the unnecessary `.clone()` in the `get` function.

Please note that this code, while compiles, is not perfect yet – the `RwLock` locks should last shorter (`get` and `post` should take `&RwLock<HashMap<String,String>>` as an argument and perform the locking by themselves). The `.unwrap()` also may be handled in a better way. You can also consider using some lockless concurrent hashmap, there should be some crates for that, but I'm not into the topic, so I won't recommend any.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanations really helped.

Comment: Thanks, @krdln. Could you update this sample for the latest Hyper 0.12.x?