# Sharing dynamic state between #[test]s

Tags: rust

How do I share state between tests, short of storing it externally (e.g. environment variables, file, etc)?

[Stainless](https://github.com/reem/stainless#example) has a setup macro thing named `before_each`, and I'm thinking of a similar thing, say `shared_values`, but whose variables would be accessible to all tests, and which would also be ran once (at the beginning of the test suite).

Comment: In my case, I want to run tests against some web-based API, and I need to get a login token to be used by each test (which in turn will be used by each API call).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's nothing special about tests. They are "just" functions that run in multiple threads. Therefore, one solution is do the same thing you would in other code: [create a global mutable singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/155423):

```rust
use once_cell::sync::Lazy; // 1.5.2

static DATABASE: Lazy<String> = Lazy::new(|| format!("{} {}", "This was", "expensive"));

#[test]
fn one() {
    println!("{}", *DATABASE);
}

#[test]
fn two() {
    println!("{}", *DATABASE);
}
```

The test framework provides no hooks for an "after" callback, so there is no nice avenue to clean up this resource. `Drop` will not be called for singleton variables either.

Comment: Note: I confirm `Drop` is not called for `lazy_static` variables; valgrind *will* complain :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. what's one more memory leak between friends, really? On a serious note, you can always add a suppression to Valgrind if you are deliberately attempting to leak one thing but still want to be warned about other accidental leaks.

Comment: Not great when `Drop` is the thing that stops your docker container :(