# How can I access a thread-local LocalKey static variable?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use the thread-local [`LocalKey`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.LocalKey.html) to have a global game variable that the user can set once at the start of playing.

I finally got it to compile while setting a new `PLAYER_NAME` in a `with` block:

```
use std::thread::LocalKey;
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;

thread_local! {
    pub static PLAYER_NAME: String = String::from("player-one");
}

fn main() {
    let p: String = String::from("new-name");

    PLAYER_NAME.with(|mut player_name| {
        let player_name = p;
    });

    println!("PLAYER_NAME is: {:?}", PLAYER_NAME);
}
```

This prints out:

```
PLAYER_NAME is: LocalKey { .. }
```

How do I print the string value of `PLAYER_NAME`?  Do I have to use a `with` block every time I want to read it too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Do I have to use a `with` block every time I want to read it too?

Yes if you are accessing `PLAYER_NAME` directly - see [@Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46866690/1600898) for an example. But what you'd typically do in a real program is encapsulate the access to the global in functions, which buy you the usage pattern you know from other languages without loss of performance or convenience. For example:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

thread_local! {
    pub static PLAYER_NAME: RefCell<String>
        = RefCell::new("player-one".to_string());
}

fn set_player_name(name: String) {
    PLAYER_NAME.with(|player_name| {
        *player_name.borrow_mut() = name
    });
}

fn get_player_name() -> String {
    PLAYER_NAME.with(|player_name| player_name.borrow().clone())
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(get_player_name(), "player-one".to_string());
    set_player_name("mini me".to_string());
    assert_eq!(get_player_name(), "mini me".to_string());
}
```

If you don't want the player name to be per-thread, then replace `thread_local!` with [`lazy_static!`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static), `RefCell` with a `RwLock`, `borrow()` with `read()`, `borrow_mut()` with `write()`, and you will no longer need the `with`.

Comment: *without loss of performance* — I'm not sure I follow you; there's still the underlying performance hit of checking if the variable is initialized and initializing it if not, why do you say that this loss of performance is negated? *If you don't want the player name to be per-thread* — seems like `thread_local!` doesn't really fit with that concept.

Comment: @Shepmaster Re performance, I was referring to the fact that I expect the compiler to inline the call, so the effect should be the same as the `with`. (Technically my proposed getter invokes `clone` so it's slower than pure `with`, but the code inside the `with` would likely *also* clone the string to get it outside.)

Comment: @Shepmaster Re thread-local, the idea was not to use `thread_local!` in that case, which the answer neglected to actually mention. Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: The performance is also made worse by the fact that you can't return a reference to the string. `get_player_name` is forced to clone.

Comment: @JosephGarvin If you're worried about performance of the string clone, you can easily make `get_player_name()` [return `Rc<String>` instead](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d0e4a8af88e39ef8ac9b22de75abdeaf). As mentioned in previous comments, "no loss of performance" refers to `PLAYER_NAME.with()` in `get_player_name()` being inlinable by the compiler and therefore a zero-cost abstraction.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I print the string value of `PLAYER_NAME`? Do I have to use a `with` block every time I want to read it too?

Yes. The compiler has no way of knowing which arbitrary call to `PLAYER_NAME` would be the first one and which would come after. **Every** time you access the thread-local, it has to be checked to ensure that it's been initialized and do so if it hasn't. `with` performs that check.

---

Beyond that, you have a number of other issues. Rust is a compiled language, which means you should **listen to the warnings it prints**.

```
let player_name = p;
```

This declares a new variable that shadows the closure variable `player_name`, it does not set it.

You are then attempting to mutate an immutable reference, which cannot work. You'll need some kind of internal mutability, such as [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html).

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

thread_local! {
    pub static PLAYER_NAME: RefCell<String> = RefCell::new(String::from("player-one"));
}

fn main() {
    let p: String = String::from("new-name");

    PLAYER_NAME.with(|player_name| {
        *player_name.borrow_mut() = p;
    });

    PLAYER_NAME.with(|player_name| {
        println!("The name is: {}", player_name.borrow());
    });
}
```

See also:

- [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/155423)

---

I'd also **strongly** encourage you to just try and use standard Rust references and pass values down from a parent context. It's usually a lot easier to understand than some magical semi-global state, especially if you are new to Rust.