# How to store global state in Rust when using wasm-bindgen?

Tags: rust

I'm attempting to write a data store in Rust that receives objects from JavaScript across the wasm-bindgen boundary and stores them for later retrieval.  This is a simplified version of what I was hoping would work:

```
static mut MAP: HashMap<i32, String> = HashMap::new();

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn add_value(index: i32, value: String) {
    unsafe {
        MAP.insert(index, value);
    }
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn get_value(index: i32) -> String {
    unsafe {
        (*MAP.get(&index).unwrap()).clone()
    }
}
```

However I get this error from the Rust compiler:

```
error[E0015]: calls in statics are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
```

How can I store state so that subsequent calls across the wasm-bindgen boundary can retrieve previously stored values?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Thank you - using lazy-static with a Mutex seems to be working.  I'm good with marking this already answered.