# Store immutable instances of Rust struct, but where?

Tags: rust

Sometimes, it’s handy to have a few instances of a `struct` stored and accessible everywhere.

For instance, if I want to store some meta-data about a currency in a struct like this:

```rust
struct Currency {
    name: &'static str,
    iso_symbols: Vec<&'static str>
}
```

I would then create an instance of `Currency` for every major currency. As these property don’t change, it could be hard-coded, at least for some currencies.

I tried to use `const`, which would work without a Vec (the `vec!` macro does an allocation, which is not allowed in `const`).

```rust
const BTC: Currency = Currency {
    name: "Bitcoin",
    iso_symbols: vec!["BTC", "XBT"]
};
```

So what workaround would you suggest to store a bunch of instance of `Currency` (for EUR, USD, BTC…)?

Here, in the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d87c5a184b095499b3ff174ee0538b86).

---

EDIT: My question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton). The only difference is that I don’t need a mutable singleton, so the “Non-answer answer” doesn’t apply, right? The `lazy_static` idea is great though!

It might be interesting to keep this question around since I didn’t searched with the keyword `singleton` and I may not be alone to miss this way to consider the problem.

Comment: I guess you are looking for singletons. If so, you can use lazy_static crate. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton.

Comment: The proposed duplicate target also works for immutable global singletons.

Comment: That's right @E_net4. I was just wondering if the Non-answer answer applied.

Comment: Both the **non-answer answer** and the **`lazy_static`** sections apply. Being built only once and frozen afterwards makes things even easier, since you won't need to wrap it around an exclusive lock.

Comment: *It might be interesting to keep this question around since I didn’t searched with the keyword singleton and I may not be alone to miss this way to consider the problem.* -- This is exactly why duplicates exist! Questions marked as duplicates are not deleted, only closed to new answers.

Comment: I notice that `Currency` only needs `lazy_static` because it contains a `Vec`, but if the contents of the `Vec` are known at compile time and never changed, [you could just use `&'static [&'static str]` instead](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d70485d4addb03ddde9c392b46c219af). This works with either a `const` or a `static`.

Comment: @trentcl Thanks for the idea with &'static [&'static str]. Am I supposed to do something to mark the question as duplicated?

Comment: @E_net4wisheshappyholidays Would you say this global state is to be avoided too, as the **non-answer** section?

Comment: There should be a link you can click to agree to the duplicate, but I don't know which it is for you, maybe "close"?

Comment: @trentcl I first clicked to edit my question, to explain how it was different from the duplicate, so now, I’m stuck. By the way, why didn’t you put the solution with &'static […] as an answer?

Comment: Because wanting to put a `Vec` in a global static is a valid thing to do, even if it would be rare, so "just don't use `Vec`" would have been another non-answer :)

Comment: @trentcl I undestand ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, the `lazy_static` crate works well.

```rust
pub struct Currency {
    name: &'static str,
    iso_symbols: Vec<&'static str>,
}

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref BTC: Currency = Currency {
        name: "Bitcoin",
        iso_symbols: vec!["BTC", "XBT"]
    };
}

fn main() {
    println!("{} {:?}", BTC.name, BTC.iso_symbols);
}
```

We have this global (with `pub`) variable BTC I was looking for.