# How do I await a function which takes a callback?

Tags: rust, async-await

There's a function:

```rust
pub fn vigem_target_add_async(
        vigem: PVIGEM_CLIENT,
        target: PVIGEM_TARGET,
        result: PFN_VIGEM_TARGET_ADD_RESULT,
    ) -> VIGEM_ERROR;
```

where `PFN_VIGEM_TARGET_ADD_RESULT` is a callback type:

```
pub type PFN_VIGEM_TARGET_ADD_RESULT = ::std::option::Option<unsafe extern "C" fn(EVT_VIGEM_TARGET_ADD_RESULT)>;
```

Can I do with async/await something like:

```
vigem_target_add_async(vigem, target, FUNC::BOILERPLATE_FUTURE).await
```

And get `EVT_VIGEM_TARGET_ADD_RESULT`?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is with a [`oneshot`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.5/futures/channel/oneshot/fn.channel.html) channel:

```
use futures::channel::oneshot;

let (send, recv) = oneshot::channel::<EVT_VIGEM_TARGET_ADD_RESULT>();

vigem_target_add_async (vigem, target, |r| send.send (r).unwrap());
let result = recv.await;
```

Comment: It wont work, because `PFN_VIGEM_TARGET_ADD_RESULT` is function, not a closure

Comment: Does `PFN_VIGEM_TARGET_ADD_RESULT` accept a "user data" parameter? If yes, you use that to pass `send`. If not, its API is broken and there is no clean way to use it in asynchronous code (including multi-thread) in any language. In that case, you will need to use some global variable to store `send` and make sure that it is never called in parallel.

Comment: No, it does not support user data

Comment: Then you can still use a `oneshot` channel, but you will need to put the `send` part in a global variable so that your callback can access it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27826181/5397009) for ways to make a mutable global variable in Rust.

Comment: You will also need to make sure that there is never more than one call to `vigem_target_add_async` active simultaneously to avoid conflicting accesses to the global variable.