# Rust | Why when i creating new hash map it gives me error

Tags: rust

I want to alloc static hashmap,but ig gives me error "calls in statics are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants". [image]
How can i fix this error?

Comment: Don't paste an image of your code but your code itself (and optionally a link to a playground exhibit) !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [lazy_static](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/1.4.0/lazy_static/) using a [RwLock](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) (as you seem to update the content dynamically).

RwLock allow you to read and write to the HashMap without the need of a Mutex, this in fact allow you to have multiple reader (but only one writer). If your program is not async, then just leave the HashMap as mut in the lazy_static.
A Mutex is also a good option, but it only allow you to have one reader at a time, do some bench for your program and chose the best solution for you.

Example of a lazy_static Vec with RwLock [here](https://github.com/speculare-cloud/speculare-pgcdc/blob/master/src/main.rs#L36).