# Understanding a thread safe RwLock<Arc<T>> mechanism in Rust

Tags: struct, rust, localization, macros, config

## Background

I am *completely new* to Rust (started yesterday) and I'm trying to ensure I've understood correctly.  I am looking to write a configuration system for a 'game', and want it to be fast access but occasionally mutable.  To start, I wanted to investigate localization which seemed a reasonable use case for static configuration (as I appreciate such things are generally not 'Rusty' otherwise).  I came up with the following (working) code, based in part on [this blog post](https://blog.sentry.io/2018/04/05/you-cant-rust-that) (found via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65200809)).  I've included here for reference, but feel free to skip it over for now...

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! localize {
    (@single $($x:tt)*) => (());
    (@count $($rest:expr),*) => (<[()]>::len(&[$(localize!(@single $rest)),*]));

    ($name:expr $(,)?) => { LOCALES.lookup(&Config::current().language, $name) };
    ($name:expr, $($key:expr => $value:expr,)+) => { localize!(&Config::current().language, $name, $($key => $value),+) };
    ($name:expr, $($key:expr => $value:expr),*) => ( localize!(&Config::current().language, $name, $($key => $value),+) );

    ($lang:expr, $name:expr $(,)?) => { LOCALES.lookup($lang, $name) };
    ($lang:expr, $name:expr, $($key:expr => $value:expr,)+) => { localize!($lang, $name, $($key => $value),+) };
    ($lang:expr, $name:expr, $($key:expr => $value:expr),*) => ({
        let _cap = localize!(@count $($key),*);
        let mut _map : ::std::collections::HashMap<String, _>  = ::std::collections::HashMap::with_capacity(_cap);
        $(
            let _ = _map.insert($key.into(), $value.into());
        )*
        LOCALES.lookup_with_args($lang, $name, &_map)
    });
}

use fluent_templates::{static_loader, Loader};
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
use unic_langid::{langid, LanguageIdentifier};

static_loader! {
    static LOCALES = {
        locales: "./resources",
        fallback_language: "en-US",
        core_locales: "./resources/core.ftl",
        // Removes unicode isolating marks around arguments, you typically
        // should only set to false when testing.
        customise: |bundle| bundle.set_use_isolating(false)
    };
}
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Config {
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    debug_mode: bool,
    language: LanguageIdentifier,
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
impl Config {
    pub fn current() -> Arc<Config> {
        CURRENT_CONFIG.with(|c| c.read().unwrap().clone())
    }
    pub fn make_current(self) {
        CURRENT_CONFIG.with(|c| *c.write().unwrap() = Arc::new(self))
    }
    pub fn set_debug(debug_mode: bool) {
        CURRENT_CONFIG.with(|c| {
            let mut writer = c.write().unwrap();
            if writer.debug_mode != debug_mode {
                let mut config = (*Arc::clone(&writer)).clone();
                config.debug_mode = debug_mode;
                *writer = Arc::new(config);
            }
        })
    }
    pub fn set_language(language: &str) {
        CURRENT_CONFIG.with(|c| {
            let l: LanguageIdentifier = language.parse().expect("Could not set language.");
            let mut writer = c.write().unwrap();
            if writer.language != l {
                let mut config = (*Arc::clone(&writer)).clone();
                config.language = l;
                *writer = Arc::new(config);
            }
        })
    }
}

impl Default for Config {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Config {
            debug_mode: false,
            language: langid!("en-US"),
        }
    }
}

thread_local! {
    static CURRENT_CONFIG: RwLock<Arc<Config>> = RwLock::new(Default::default());
}

fn main() {
    Config::set_language("en-GB");
    println!("{}", localize!("apologize"));
}
```

*I've not included the tests for brevity.  I would welcome feedback on the `localize` macro too (as I'm not sure whether I've done that right).*

## Question

### Understanding `Arc` cloning

However, my main question is on this bit of code in particular (there is a similar example in `set_language` too):

```
    pub fn set_debug(debug_mode: bool) {
        CURRENT_CONFIG.with(|c| {
            let mut writer = c.write().unwrap();
            if writer.debug_mode != debug_mode {
                let mut config = (*Arc::clone(&writer)).clone();
                config.debug_mode = debug_mode;
                *writer = Arc::new(config);
            }
        })
    }
```

Although this works, I want to ensure it is the right approach.  From my understanding it

1. Get's a write lock on the config Arc struct.
2. Checks for changes, and, if changed:
3. Calls `Arc::clone()` on the writer (which will automatically `DeRefMut` the parameter to an Arc before cloning).  This doesn't actually 'clone' the struct but increments the reference counter (so should be fast)?
4. Call `Config::clone` due to step 3 being wrapped in (*...) - is this the right approach?  My understanding is this *does* now clone the `Config`, producing a mutable owned instance, which I can then modify.
5. Mutates the new config setting the new `debug_mode`.
6. Creates a new `Arc<Config>` from this owned `Config`.
7. Updates the static CURRENT_CONFIG.
8. Releases the reference counter to the old `Arc<Config>` (potentially freeing the memory if nothing else is currently using it).
9. Releases the write lock.

If I understand this correctly, then only one memory alloc will occur in step 4.  Is that right?  Is step 4 the right way to go about this?

### Understanding performance implications

Similarly, this code:

```
LOCALES.lookup(&Config::current().language, $name)
```

Should be quick under normal use as it uses this function:

```
    pub fn current() -> Arc<Config> {
        CURRENT_CONFIG.with(|c| c.read().unwrap().clone())
    }
```

Which gets a ref-counted pointer to the current config, without actually copying it (the `clone()` should call `Arc::clone()` as above), using a read lock (fast unless a write is occurring).

### Understanding `thread_local!` macro use

If all that is good, then great!  However, I'm then stuck on this last bit of code:

```
thread_local! {
    static CURRENT_CONFIG: RwLock<Arc<Config>> = RwLock::new(Default::default());
}
```

Surely this is wrong?  Why are we creating the CURRENT_CONFIG as a `thread_local`.  My understanding (admittedly from other languages, combined with [the limited docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.thread_local.html)) means that there will be a unique version to the currently executing thread, which is pointless as a thread cannot interrupt itself?  Normally I would expect a truly static `RwLock` shared across multiple thread? Am I misunderstanding something or is this a bug in the [original blog post](https://blog.sentry.io/2018/04/05/you-cant-rust-that)?

Indeed, the following test seems to confirm my suspicions:

```
    #[test]
    fn config_thread() {
        Config::set_language("en-GB");
        assert_eq!(langid!("en-GB"), Config::current().language);
        let tid = thread::current().id();
        let new_thread =thread::spawn(move || {
            assert_ne!(tid, thread::current().id());
            assert_eq!(langid!("en-GB"), Config::current().language);
        });

        new_thread.join().unwrap();
    }
```

Produces (demonstrating that the config is not shared across thread):

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `LanguageIdentifier { language: Language(Some("en")), script: None, region: Some(Region("GB")), variants: None }`,
 right: `LanguageIdentifier { language: Language(Some("en")), script: None, region: Some(Region("US")), variants: None }`
```

Comment: Removing the `thread_local` does appear to fix my tests, including ensuring `Config` state is shared across threads and updatable safely, full code below (makes use of latest `SyncLazy` from nightly builds though:

Comment: [full code is available here](https://gist.github.com/thargy/f64e26c3c3321be10de1705ea3f47ef2)

Comment: `(*Arc::clone(&writer)).clone()` looks like an unnecessary clone of the `Arc` - `writer.as_ref().clone()` should achieve the same purpose without the inner clone. While cloning an `Arc` is cheap compared to copying an allocated type, it is not free because it involves memory barriers when manipulating the atomic counter. (The counter is updated once when creating the temporary clone of the `Arc` and again when it is destroyed - and those cannot be optimized away because they can be visible to other threads, so the compiler must generate both adjustments.)

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342, does `Arc::_as_ref()` increment the ref count correctly?

Comment: `as_ref()` doesn't increment the refcount at all. It gives you a `&T` that is not allowed to outlive the `Arc` that handed it out. You can use that `&T`, in this case to call `T::clone()` without touching the reference count of the `Arc`. And the fact that the reference can't outlive the `Arc` guarantees that the object cannot be destructed while you're using the reference.

Answer (score 3):

The section of the blog post you are referring to is, in my opinion, not very good.

You are correct that `RwLock` here is bogus - it can be replaced with a `RefCell` as it is thread local.

The justification for the approach in the blog post is flimsy:

> However, in the previous example we introduced interior mutability. Imagine we have multiple threads running, all referencing the same config, but one flips a flag. What happens to concurrently running code that now is not expecting the flag to randomly flip?

The entire point of a `RwLock` is that modifications cannot be made while the object is locked for reading (i.e. the `RwLockReadGuard` returned from `RwLock::read()` is alive). So an `Arc<RwLock<Config>>` won't have your flags "randomly flipped" while a read lock is taken out. (Granted, it can be an issue, if you release the lock and take it again, and assume the flag has not changed in the meantime.)

The section also doesn't specify how an update to a configuration would actually take place. You'd need a mechanism to signal the other threads that a config change had taken place (ex. a channel) and the threads themselves would have to update their own thread-local variable with the new configuration.

Ultimately, I'd just consider that section as bad advice, and certainly not tailored to a beginner.

Comment: I agree overall the blog is very clumsy and incomplete. I think the only additional useful thing to mention to OP is that, overall, this is just implementing a very basic [RCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update) pattern. The [`arc_swap`](https://docs.rs/arc-swap/1.3.0/arc_swap/) crate more or less handles this completely without the need for a heavy-weight lock.

Comment: Thanks, @GManNickG, that looks exactly like what I need!

Comment: Thanks @[Colonel Thirty Two], that confirmed my suspicion.