# how to share information globally in gtk-rs Application

Tags: rust, gtk-rs

I am trying to build an Application in Rust with gtk-rs. When the user creates a new project the path to the project root needs to be stored in some way so that it is accessible to all of the application.
Things I have tried to solve this:

- Create a mutable static String (unsafe and thus probably not a viable solution)
- Store the variable into a file which is slow and stupid for obvious reasons. Works though...
- Use `lazy_static!` as suggested in [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton) Post. But it also says that this is generally not the preferred way. So I tried the next thing.
- Create a `mut project_root: &mut String` and pass it to any function that needs it. Now the issue with this is, when I need to call `new_proj_menu_item.connect_activate(move |_| new_project_listener::add_listener(&file_tree_view, project_root));` to set up the listener for the menu Item, the compiler tells me: "`project_root` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement E0759 ...is captured here... Note: ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here" Which I do not fully understand but seems to be related to the first thing I tried (project_root is the String).

Now my question is: How would I go about storing a variable like this so that it is accessible from the entire project? Is there maybe a GTK internal way that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why storing the variable into a file is slow and stupid. It's the standard as far as I know, you typically access that file less that once per minute. If you mean communicating between threads or functions, you definitely should redesign the app. Use mpsc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).