# How to use common BTreeMap variable in rust(single thread)

Tags: rust

Here is my original simplified code, I want to use a global variable instead of the variables in separate functions.  What's the suggestion method in rust?
BTW, I've tried to use global or change to function parameter, both are nightmare for a beginner. Too difficult to solve the lifetime & variable type cast issue.
This simple program is only a single thread tool, so, in C language, it is not necessary the extra mutex.

```
// version 1
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

// Trying but failed
// let mut guess_number = BTreeMap::new();
//  | ^^^ expected item

fn read_csv() {
    let mut guess_number = BTreeMap::new();

    let lines = ["Tom,4", "John,6"];
    for line in lines.iter() {
        let split = line.split(",");
        let vec: Vec<_> = split.collect();
        println!("{} {:?}", line, vec);
        let number: u16 = vec[1].trim().parse().unwrap();
        guess_number.insert(vec[0], number);
    }
    for (k, v) in guess_number {
        println!("{} {:?}", k, v);
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut guess_number = BTreeMap::new();
    guess_number.insert("Tom", 3);
    guess_number.insert("John", 7);
    if guess_number.contains_key("John") {
        println!("John's number={:?}", guess_number.get("John").unwrap());
    }

    read_csv();
}
```

To explain how hard it is for a beginner, by pass parameter

```
// version 2
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn read_csv(guess_number: BTreeMap) {
    //                    ^^^^^^^^ expected 2 generic arguments
    let lines = ["Tom,4", "John,6"];
    for line in lines.iter() {
        let split = line.split(",");
        let vec: Vec<_> = split.collect();
        println!("{} {:?}", line, vec);
        let number: u16 = vec[1].trim().parse().unwrap();
        guess_number.insert(vec[0], number);
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut guess_number = BTreeMap::new();
    guess_number.insert("Tom", 3);
    guess_number.insert("John", 7);
    if guess_number.contains_key("John") {
        println!("John's number={:?}", guess_number.get("John").unwrap());
    }

    read_csv(guess_number);
    for (k, v) in guess_number {
        println!("{} {:?}", k, v);
    }
}
```

After some effort, try & error to get the possible work type BTreeMap<&str, i32>

```
// version 3
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
fn read_csv(guess_number: &BTreeMap<&str, i32>) {
    // let mut guess_number = BTreeMap::new();

    let lines = ["Tom,4", "John,6"];
    for line in lines.iter() {
        let split = line.split(",");
        let vec: Vec<_> = split.collect();
        println!("{} {:?}", line, vec);
        let number: i32 = vec[1].trim().parse().unwrap();
        guess_number.insert(vec[0], number);
    }
    for (k, v) in guess_number {
        println!("{} {:?}", k, v);
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut guess_number: BTreeMap<&str, i32> = BTreeMap::new();
    guess_number.insert("Tom", 3);
    guess_number.insert("John", 7);
    if guess_number.contains_key("John") {
        println!("John's number={:?}", guess_number.get("John").unwrap());
    }

    read_csv(&guess_number);
    for (k, v) in guess_number {
        println!("{} {:?}", k, v);
    }
}
```

will cause following error

```
7  | fn read_csv(guess_number: &BTreeMap<&str, i32>) {
   |                           -------------------- help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut BTreeMap<&str, i32>`
...
16 |         guess_number.insert(vec[0], number);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `guess_number` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

The final answer (seems not suggest use global in Rust, so use 'mutable reference').

```
// version 4
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
fn read_csv(guess_number: &mut BTreeMap<&str, i32>) {
    let lines = ["Tom,4", "John,6"];
    for line in lines.iter() {
        let split = line.split(",");
        let vec: Vec<_> = split.collect();
        println!("{} {:?}", line, vec);
        let number: i32 = vec[1].trim().parse().unwrap();
        guess_number.insert(vec[0], number);
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut guess_number: BTreeMap<&str, i32> = BTreeMap::new();
    guess_number.insert("Tom", 3);
    guess_number.insert("John", 7);
    if guess_number.contains_key("John") {
        println!("John's number={:?}", guess_number.get("John").unwrap());
    }

    read_csv(&mut guess_number);
    for (k, v) in guess_number {
        println!("{} {:?}", k, v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass the btree as parameter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton)

Comment: If you found a solution yourself you should add it as an answer instead of adding it to the question via an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not specific to `BTreeMap`s but for pretty much all data types, such as numbers, strings, vectors, enums, etc.

If you want to *pass* a variable (value) from one function to another, you can do that in various ways in Rust. Typically you either *move* the value or you pass a reference to it. *Moving* is something quite specific to Rust and its *ownership* model. This is really essential, so if you have serious intentions to learn Rust, I strongly suggest you read the chapter [Understanding Ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) from "the book". Don't get discouraged if you don't understand it from one reading. Spend as much time as needed, as you really can't move forward w/o this knowledge.

As for global variables, there are very few situations where they should be used. In Rust using global variables is slightly more difficult, compared to most other languages. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton) is quite useful, although you might find it a bit difficult to comprehend. My advice to a beginner would be to first fully understand the basic concept of moving and passing references.

Comment: For simple variable like u32, it is easy, but for complex type, it is not the same.

Comment: Re-read the book, finally get a solution by passing parameter, the important document in the rust book is 'Mutable Reference', check my version 4 code