# Rust way to store cached mysql statements

Tags: sql, rust, prepared-statement

I am trying to make a small rust webserver which uses mysql. It is a small project that am using as a learning experience more than anything. I want to know what the best practice is for storing prepared statements in rust with crate mysql=*.

I come from a java background (academic) which means that I would accomplish the same task by making static statements like this:

```
    private static PreparedStatement SOME_STATEMENT;
```

Then I would make the statement when the database is initialized

```
    SOME_STATEMENT = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(Distinct SOME_FIELD) FROM SOME_TABLE");
```

Then, I would execute the statment by abstracting it via a method

```
  public synchronized static int someDatabaseQuery()  throws SQLException{
    try (ResultSet results = SOME_STATEMENT.executeQuery()) {
      results.next();
      return results.getInt(1);
    }
  }
```

This is relatively trivial in java given how it allows for what rust considers "unsafe" code. What is the best "Rust" way to accomplish the same task without using external dependencies like Lazy static (if this is even possible)

My only guess so far is to make a struct like

```
    pub struct Database {
        url: String,
        pool: Pool,
        conn: PooledConn,
        stmtOne: Stmt, 
        .... // more statements
    }
```

then have a new method that initiates a struct

```
    pub fn new(
        database_username: &String,
        password: &String,
        database_url: &String,
        database_name: &String,
    ) -> Result<Database, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let url = format!(
            "mysql://{}:{}@{}/{}",
            database_username, password, database_url, database_name
        );

        let opts = Opts::from_url(url.as_str())?;
        let pool = Pool::new(opts)?;

        let mut conn = match pool.get_conn() {
            Ok(conn) => conn,
            Err(err) => return Err(Box::new(err)),
        };

        let mut stmtOne = conn.prep("").unwrap();
        ...// more initiations 

        Ok(Database {
            url,
            pool,
            conn,
            stmtOne,
            ... // more statements
        })
    }
```

I find this very tedious and believe that rust has a better way, what is the best way to do this in rust?

**EDIT: Solution**
as suggested by @Chayim

First make a struct

```
pub struct Database {
    url: String,
    pool: Pool,
    conn: PooledConn,
}
```

Make the static declarations with OnceLock

```
static SOME_STATEMENT: OnceLock<Statement> = OnceLock::new();
static SOME_STATEMENT_TWO: OnceLock<Statement> = OnceLock::new();
```

Then adjust my previous initiation method to make the static statements

```
    pub fn new(
        database_username: &String,
        password: &String,
        database_url: &String,
        database_name: &String,
    ) -> Database {
        let url = format!(
            "mysql://{}:{}@{}/{}",
            database_username, password, database_url, database_name
        );

        let opts = Opts::from_url(url.as_str()).unwrap();
        let pool = Pool::new(opts).unwrap();

        match pool.get_conn() {
            Ok(mut conn) => {
                SOME_STATEMENT.get_or_init(|| conn.prep(" SELECT USERNAME FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE USERNAME=:username").unwrap());
                SOME_STATEMENT_TWO.get_or_init(|| conn.prep(" ... some other query").unwrap());
                return Database { url, pool, conn };
            }
            Err(err) => panic!("Unable to initialize database: {err}"),
        };
    }
```

And finally call them in a method

```rust
    pub fn some_database_query(&mut self, name: &String) -> Option<Vec<String>> {
        match SOME_STATEMENT.get() {
            Some(stmt) => Some(self.conn.exec(stmt, params! {"username" => name}).unwrap()),
            None => None,
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a particular problem with trying to use a `static` like you have done in Java if that's how you want to do it. However, Rust's `static`s must be initialized during compile time. You can defer initialization until runtime by using one of the routes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton). Using `std::sync::OnceLock` does not require external dependencies (though mysql includes many itself so its weird that it would bother you - many of the "Rust" ways to do things rely on dependencies).

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks for the input, am still operating under the impression that rust is a "save" language, thereby avoiding most stuff that is not encouraged by regular rust rules. I do plan on using RwLock and simular approaches. In short, I am asking for any wisdom that i may have missed. I do think that your addition contributes to my general perspective on guidelines for writing rust.

Comment: Using `static` should be fine, I don't see why not. The critical question is, is your data lazily-initialized (initialized only once) or can change?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, if i understand your comment correctly, yes it is only initialized once, given that any statements I plan on using will be cached, and should only be initialized once at startup. The main problem i've encountered is that before I can make a statement I have to make a connection `Pool::new(opts)?.get_conn()`, it is my understanding that this cannot be accomplished staticacally.

Comment: Then why can't you use `OnceLock`?