# How to share variables between functions in an impl in rust. I don't think static will work for me

Tags: rust

Forgive my ignorance, I just started with rust yesterday.

I'm using the example in the Readme here: https://github.com/niiightmarexd/windows-capture

I want to add ecal to it. https://github.com/kopernikusauto/ecal-rs

I'm still trying to understand the rust architecture and impl. It's like a class extend almost. WindowsCaptureHandler has on_frame_arrived. But this is called every time a frame arrives so I don't want to initialize ecal there. But I don't know how to either initialize globally or init in new and pass that to on_frame_arrived.

I've tried a number of permutations of something like:

```
thread_local!(static PUB:ecal::Publisher<ecal_rs::Frame, Prost<ecal_rs::Frame>> = Publisher::<ecal_rs::Frame>::new("/Frame"));
```

But the compiler complains because it's a result that's returned. I think that makes sense:
https://github.com/kopernikusauto/ecal-rs/blob/651dbc1a1d87759730c17ae0e2f7978e7729c6a2/src/lib.rs#L285C9-L285C9

I tried adding `?` but I don't think I can unpack in this scope.

How do I globally initialize ecal, or init in new and pass that to another function?

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this open as I'm not sure if there's a more idiomatic way to do this.

I used [lazy-static](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/latest/lazy_static/) as such

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref PUB: ecal::Publisher<ecal_rs::Frame, Prost<ecal_rs::Frame>> = {
        let mut publisher = Publisher::<ecal_rs::Frame>::new("/frame").unwrap();
        publisher
    };
}
```

Then I could use it globally and it works great:
`PUB.send(&screen)?;`

Comment: `lazy_static` is the correct way, but instead of `lazy_static` you should use [`once_cell::sync::Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html) that has a more modern API, or even avoid dependencies altogether by using [`std`'s `OnceLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html) (there is also `LazyLock`, but it is currently unstable). See [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/7884305) for more.