# How does the compiler optimize reads/writes to `static mut`?

Tags: rust, llvm, compiler-optimization

I have written code that works somewhat like this:

```rust
#![no_std]

static mut DATA: usize = 0;

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe fn update() {
    DATA = 1;
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe fn wait_for_data() {
    while DATA == 0 {}
    DATA = 1;
}
```

In my case, the `update` function is called by a hardware interrupt and `wait_for_data` runs in the main program. Because of this, we can assume that `DATA` will change during the `while` loop. I assumed `static mut` would tell the compiler that this address may be shared across mutliple concurrent execution threads. However, the compiler optimizes this code by jumping into an infinite loop if `DATA == 0` on the first iteration.

Now my questions are:

- Does the compiler assume no concurrent access to `DATA` can occur?
- Would this use-case require volatile read/write or atomics?

Comment: I'm no expert, but that is a book case for [atomics](https://marabos.nl/atomics/).

Comment: Use `atomic` with `memory_order_relaxed` to get the asm you're looking for, stopping the compiler from hoisting the load out of the loop.  (spin-wait isn't very good, though, consider something equivalent to C++20 wait / notify if your real use-case involves waiting for more than a few tens or hundreds of microseconds.)

Comment: This actually need volatile atomic, which Rust doesn't provide.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Why `volatile atomic`?  Because it runs from a hardware interrupt handler?  An interrupt handler is like a signal handler, taking over the context of an existing thread.  C++ `atomic` Just Works from signal handlers as long as its lock_free so it can't deadlock with the main thread, so I'm surprised Rust would be different.  Or some other reason, like a potentially-infinite spin-wait loop?

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, I thought interrupt handler is like MMIO. My mistake, then.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is, that you tell the compiler you know what you're doing (`wait_for_data` is `unsafe`). But using `PartialEq` (through `==`) means `wait_for_data` takes a shared reference to `DATA` (the signature is `fn eq(&self, other: &Rhs) -> bool;`), So you guarantee, that there are no mutalbe references to `DATA` because that would be [UB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html) per:

> - Breaking the [pointer aliasing rules](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#pointer-aliasing-rules). `Box<T>`, `&mut T` and `&T` follow LLVM’s scoped [noalias](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#noalias) model, except if the `&T` contains an [`UnsafeCell<U>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html). References and boxes must not be [dangling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html#dangling-pointers) while they are live. The exact liveness duration is not specified, but some bounds exist:
>
>   - For references, the liveness duration is upper-bounded by the syntactic lifetime assigned by the borrow checker; it cannot be live any *longer* than that lifetime.
>   - Each time a reference or box is passed to or returned from a function, it is considered live.
>   - When a reference (but not a `Box`!) is passed to a function, it is live at least as long as that function call, again except if the `&T` contains an [`UnsafeCell<U>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html).

In other words, there can't be an exclusive reference anywhere that points to the `DATA` as you're taking a shared reference. This means the compiler can safely assume `DATA` doesn't change, and optimize the loop.

In fact a `static mut` is very rarely what you want, very hard to use correctly and rarely needed. You can look in [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton) for various ways to do what you want to do. With a `usize` I'd go for a [`static DATA: AtomicUsize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicUsize.html) instead, which allows to do the checks the way you intended them to, maybe in combination with a [`Condvar`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html) to avoid the busy loop.