How am I supposed to have a writeable static object from different parts of my code?
I'm used to C++ that'll allow you to have a writable static object, whether in the global namespace, a user-defined namespace or class. However it seems in Rust this isn't kosher. In order to do so you have to wrap the write access to the static variable with unsafe. And I have even read that static mut may be removed/deprecated from the language. What are my options in the following:
use std::collections::HashMap;

static mut my_dict: HashMap<u32, u32>;



fn main() {
    
    dosomething();

    
}

fn dosomething() -> ()
{/* MAY BE WRITTEN FROM THIS MODULE OR PERHAPS ANOTHER MODULE */
    my_dict.insert(3, 3);

}

The options I can think of are:

Wrap all write accesses in unsafe {}. I could get used to the fact that Rust forces you to do this and be forced to think carefully anytime I write to a static mut. However if it's true that static mut will be removed or deprecated then this isn't even an option.
A couple of people suggested "dependency injection", which I assume is a fancy term for passing the object to the function that needs it as an argument everywhere. This isn't a realistic option.

What other options do I have?

In order to mutate a static safely, it needs some kind of synchronization or other assurance that you can't cause a data race: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton

Can you elaborate on why you don't think passing the argument around is not realistic? Plenty of people do it, so it's generally realistic. Is it actually not possible for you for some reason, or do you just find it inconvenient? If the former, you should include the constraint behind that, because it's likely relevant to getting the right answer.

@yshavit Oh, well, I guess you're right, it may not be as bad as I envision. Just the idea of having to pass an extra argument to every function I call does sound really awful, especially when having to pass down like 5 levels of functions. a() -> b() -> c() -> d() -> e()  And then let's just say e() needs obj1 and obj2, then a(), b(), c(), d(), that don't need obj2 have it passed to them anyway. A bunch of times I've heard people say wrap the variables in a "context" struct, but then as rightly pointed out, that breaks encapsulation, the functions just don't need everything.

@Zebrafish You can, to some degree, avoid breaking encapsulation by using traits and generics. Obviously, there are downsides to this approach, most notably that it makes everything a bit more verbose.

I will say in your defense, there are some things that are just globally available and we just accept as being naturally so: stdin/out/err, env vars, and filesystems, for example. A language could say that these are all simply passed into the main function, and after that it's up to you to pass them around as args. People would find that unreasonable, and yet accept it when they're forced to do the same with their own resources! Tbh I never thought of that particular side of the tradeoffs before.

@yshavit stdio and environment variables are global because that's how they are represented in the underlying system, not because it's ideal language design. Filesystems are a different beast entirely (I'm not sure what a "non-global filesystem handle" would even look like).

@cdhowie That doesn't mean the language has to represent them that way. Plenty of languages abstract away OS operations. As to what a non-global FS would look like, it'd be some object that has methods like "read a file", "write a file" etc. Many languages have these objects in addition to the global methods, and it's not too hard (imo) to imagine the objects being the only way (rather than just one way) to do these operations. And once you have such an object, it's not hard to imagine it passed in as an argument to main, instead of being globally available.

@yshavit Sure, though the usefulness of doing it this way versus a global value is dubious. In particular, global state is not an issue, it's mutable global state that causes problems. It's hard to imagine why such a filesystem abstraction would need to be mutable. Stdio, on the other hand, probably shouldn't actually be global. That Rust has an underlying mutex that gets locked on stdio operations is pretty good evidence of this. Likewise, environment variables being global would not really be an issue if it weren't for the fact that setenv exists.

@yshavit (Also, many C environments support declaring main with a third argument typed char** which receives the program's environment, so the idea of passing stuff to main is not exactly an esoteric concept.)

@cdhowie A filesystem is mutable state. You write to a file, you read that data that you wrote back — unless someone else (within your process, or not) wrote something else. As such, it has all the issues of mutable global state: races, non-isolated state in tests, etc. I guess I find it less hard to imagine an abstracted, non-global FS object because I've used them. ;-) Go and Java both have them, for example. I'm less familiar with Rust.

(With all that said, this is turning into a non-StackOverflow-y discussion, and I need to get to bed anyway. So I'll let you have the last word, and off to bed I go! :) )

@yshavit I enjoy a good discussion anyway. :) The counter-point to a filesystem having the same issues as global mutable state is that it's pretty much unavoidable unless your OS gives you enforced file locking, which *nix doesn't. No matter what you do, your data can be stomped on by another process. So there isn't much point in providing in-process guarantees about races since it's always possible out-of-process. IOW, the filesystem is a bit of a special case.

@cdhowie I broke my own rule, sorry! While you're mostly right, one big difference is in tests. If you have code that takes an abstracted FS object, you can supply a mocked, in-memory impl for tests. This means you don't need to worry about cleanup (which can result in tests working differently depending on the order they're run), parallelism between tests, etc. Anyway, I wasn't saying originally that the current designs are bad necessarily; just that it never occurred to me before to question them, even though on the surface they violate the principle of "don't expose global mutable state."

static mut is unsafe because there is no synchronization when a global variable is accessed by multiple threads.
One solution that you've already pointed out is to pass a &mut to a value declared elsewhere (e.g. in main()) to every function that needs it.  Regardless of whether you consider this "realistic," this is the best option for multiple reasons.  One is that you don't need the overhead of synchronized access if you aren't actually using threads, another is that it allows your function to be better tested (functions relying on global state are very difficult to test), and yet another is that you may eventually need to be able to handle multiple maps existing for different things in the same process -- and once you need that, you'll have to rewrite the whole thing anyway.
If you're hell-bent on using a global, then you need to wrap the map in a Mutex which adds synchronization.  This allows you to safely access the value from multiple threads.
But then you'll discover that you can't actually create a HashMap in const context, so now you further need a OnceLock layer.
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Mutex, OnceLock};

static MY_DICT: OnceLock<Mutex<HashMap<u32, u32>>> = OnceLock::new();

fn get_my_dict() -> &'static Mutex<HashMap<u32, u32>> {
    MY_DICT.get_or_init(Default::default)
}

fn dosomething() {
    get_my_dict().lock().unwrap().insert(3, 3);
}

Note that even if this seems simpler, this also means that you have to be extremely careful about holding locks.  It's more efficient to take a lock once for multiple operations, but if, while you're holding the lock, you call into another function that tries to take a lock, the second lock call can panic (or, worse, it might deadlock).  The technical description of this situation is that Mutex is not guaranteed to be re-entrant.
One way to solve this would be to have those inner functions take a &mut to the map, which you can then pass in from functions holding the lock -- and now we're right back at the first solution I proposed!
tl;dr: Pass a &mut to the map to the things that need access, and declare the map itself within some function such as main(). The other option is less performant and very likely to introduce panics/deadlocks.

Is static mut being removed from the language?

@Zebrafish I believe that is the goal in the 2024 edition. It's horribly unsafe, but beyond that it's actually redundant. static mut FOO: T = T::new(); can be translated to static FOO: UnsafeCell<T> = UnsafeCell::new(T::new()); and you get pretty much exactly the same capabilities.
