# Implementing "move" thread semantics

Tags: multithreading, rust, messaging, zero-copy

I want to write a function to be called like this:

```
send("message","address");
```

Where some other thread that is doing

```
let k = recv("address");
println!("{}",k);
```

sees `message`.

In particular, the message may be large, and so I'd like "move" or "zero-copy" semantics for sending the message.

In C, the solution is something like:

1. Allocate messages on the heap
2. Have a global, threadsafe hashmap that maps "address" to some memory location
3. Write pointers into the memory location on send, and wake up the receiver using a semaphore
4. Read pointers out of the memory location on receive, and wait on a  semaphore to process new messages

But according to another SO question, step #2 "[sounds like a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747785/how-to-create-a-static-mutable-hashmap)".  So I'd like to see a more Rust-idiomatic way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get these sort of move semantics automatically, and get achieve light-weight moves by placing large values into a `Box` (i.e. allocate them on the heap). Using `type ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> = Mutex<HashMap<K, V>>;` as the threadsafe hashmap (there's various ways this could be improved), one might have:

```
use std::collections::{HashMap, RingBuf};
use std::sync::Mutex;

type ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> = Mutex<HashMap<K, V>>;

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref MAP: ConcurrentHashMap<String, RingBuf<String>> = {
        Mutex::new(HashMap::new())
    }
}

fn send(message: String, address: String) {
    MAP.lock()
       // find the place this message goes
       .entry(address)
       .get()
       // create a new RingBuf if this address was empty
       .unwrap_or_else(|v| v.insert(RingBuf::new()))
       // add the message on the back
       .push_back(message)
}
fn recv(address: &str) -> Option<String> {
     MAP.lock()
        .get_mut(address)
        // pull the message off the front
        .and_then(|buf| buf.pop_front())
}
```

That code is using the [`lazy_static!`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) macro to achieve a global hashmap (it may be better to use a local object that wraps an `Arc<ConcurrentHashMap<...>`, fwiw, since global state can make reasoning about program behaviour hard). It also uses `RingBuf` as a queue, so that messages bank up for a given `address`. If you only wish to support one message at a time, the type could be `ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>`, `send` could become `MAP.lock().insert(address, message)` and `recv` just `MAP.lock().remove(address)`.

(NB. I haven't compiled this, so the types may not match up precisely.)